# Getting linker error in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am currently getting this error when I am trying to build my project which uses cocos 2dx. I am relatively new to iOS/cocos development so am not particularly familiar with this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"rcAlloc(int, rcAllocHint)", referenced from:
  duReadContourSet(rcContourSet&, duFileIO*) in libcocos2d iOS.a(RecastDump.o)
  duReadCompactHeightfield(rcCompactHeightfield&, duFileIO*) in libcocos2d iOS.a(RecastDump.o)
"rcContext::log(rcLogCategory, char const*, ...)", referenced from:
  duLogBuildTimes(rcContext&, int) in libcocos2d iOS.a(RecastDump.o)
  logLine(rcContext&, rcTimerLabel, char const*, float) in libcocos2d iOS.a(RecastDump.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: So is `rcAlloc()` and the `rcContext` class part of your source tree?

Comment: @Droppy I do not think so

Comment: Well you need to know, so you can decide if you've forgotten to implement that code or your are failing to link an external library.